# Cleanest way to iterate over a 2D container in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

Say I have a function which takes in begin and end iterators, from a 2D container. I would like to get the dimensions of the container, and then iterate over the elements using the format specified below:

```cpp
template <typename It>
void func(It st, It en) {
  int rows = ... , cols = ... ;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      // get container's index somehow using indices
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int arr[2][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};
  func(arr, arr + 2 * 3);
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this using iterators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Say I have a function which takes in begin and end iterators, from a 2D container.

Here is the first problem. In the posted snippet there are those lines:

```
int arr[2][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};
func(arr, arr + 2 * 3);
//            ^^^^^^^
```

While `arr` is commonly called a multidimensional or 2D array, it actually is an array of **2** arrays of 3 integers. It's size is *not* 6 (=2x3), but 2.

If you want to use the two iterators in the function signature, you can rewrite your func like the following:

```
// This would print out the elements
template <typename RandomIt>
void func(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
{
    // Iterates through the rows
    for (auto row = first; row < last; ++row)
    {
        // Loops through each row
        for (auto const& el : *row)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << el;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[2][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};
    func(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> b {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    func(b.cbegin(), b.cend());
}
```

> I would like to get the dimensions of the container

There are several ways to accomplish this.

If you are limiting yourself to plain arrays, you could just change the function signature and use the right template arguments and pass the array by reference:

```
template <class T, std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
void func(T const (&arr)[Rows][Cols]) { /* ... */ }
```

The Standard Library offers various free functions which could help in writing more general functions, like [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

```
template <class M>
void func(M const& m)
{
    for (size_t i{}; i < std::size(m); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j{}; j < std::size(m[i]); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << m[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

In general, you could create your own class modelling a 2D container and write accessors  returning the correct number of rows or columns.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didn't realize that I needed to use std::begin and std::end as arguments for it to work.

Comment: @dingledooper Please note that you don't *need* to use `std::begin` or `std::end`, in the first snippet (and in your program), `arr` would decay into a pointer to the first element, which is a valid iterator, but you have to choose the pointer to the end carefully: `func(arr, arr + 2);` or `func(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));` or `func(arr, arr + std::size(arr));`. The couple `std::begin()`/`std::end()` just makes the task easier and safer, not ot mention more general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to be corrected (and I'm sure I will be), but I think the answer would be only if you create your own custom iterator. You can get close-ish by doing something like this, however the 'nrows' param of the template still needs to be specified.

```cpp
template <uint32_t nrows, uint32_t ncols, typename It>
void func(It st[nrows][ncols]) {
  // int rows = ... , cols = ... ;
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
      // get container's index somehow using indices
      std::cout << st[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}

int main()
{
  int arr[2][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};
  func<2>(arr);
}
```

Comment: I recommend passing the array by reference so that nobody gets confused by the array decay.